# ListBox always auto selects first item

Tags: wpf, listbox, selecteditem

ListBox's behavior is that the first item is selected automatically, how can I avoid that??

Note: I prefer to do this with pure xaml, if you have any code-behind ideas then please don't bother yourself.

Comment: i think u meant, that when u move focus to listbox, 1st item is always selected ? (highlighted..and if u press down, the 2nd item gets the focus?)

Comment: 1) for the one who marked my question as duplicate, you didn't understand the question, i am the one who posted the duplicate as well.
2) @Madi, When the listbox is rendered, its first item is selected automatically, i want to disable this feature.

Comment: hmm.. you can use FocusManager to focus into a certain item/element..(all in xaml)... however i cant figure out how to make it focus on nothing :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to avoid first item selection by default in wpf Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257928/how-to-avoid-first-item-selection-by-default-in-wpf-listbox)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well i tried this using FocusManager.FocusedElement .. and made the intial focus to
listbox itself.. so it has the focus..but no element is selected..
if u press down or tab ..the 1st element of the listbox will be selected...

```
<Window
  ...... 
  FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=listbox2}">
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="117.333" Height="116" 
        Margin="30.667,0,0,30">
        <ListBoxItem>Jim</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Mark</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Mandy</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 15):

Try

`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"`

Answer (score 5):

remove  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" an add it with the next SelectionChanged event if needed.
This solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

You could set SelectedIndex to -1 :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" SelectedIndex="-1"/>
```

> Note: I want to do this with pure xaml, if you have any code-behind ideas then please don't bother yourself.

Unfortunately you can't do everything in XAML... you can usually avoid code-behind, but you still need to write converters, markup extensions or attached properties

Comment: I was lookin for an answer just like yours.
the only tiny problem is it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that I want to avoid this since the selection triggers a chain of executions which are processed at the SelecttionChanged handler.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a technique I use quite often.  It builds on the above example of adding the `FocusedElement` attribute to your `Window` or `UserControl`.

My deal is that I don't want ANY of the controls on my window to have focus.  The solution for me is to create a dummy control that has no UI and assign focus to that. It just so happens that `Control` fits the bill perfectly:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=focus_thief}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <!-- no renderable UI -->
        <Control Name="focus_thief"/>
        <!-- wants focus, but won't get it -->
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>First Item</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Very clever solution.The UI is doing something that is sometimes desirable but if Selected Item is restyled it still keeps an annoying blackbox when the whole control re-renders. Your solution prevents this and exists exactly where it should. I chose to rename mine to "TakeFocusToAvoidUiSelectingANonSelectedItem"

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListBox SelectioMode="Single" SelectedIndex="-1"/>
```

Comment: I don't want the selection mode to be Single.

Answer (score 1):

Is SelectedIndex the property you're looking for ? Or maybe I don't get your point...

Comment: you got my point, but when i set selectedindex to -1 or alternatively selected item to x:Null, the first item is still selected

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. Anyone found a "clean" solution?
The problem is the same here, it causes a bunch of triggers to execute.

Obvious solution/fix:

1. Remove SelectionChanged event handlers from XAML
2. Add handlers in the constructor after InitializeComponents has loaded the listbox.

Comment: Related questions and comments shuold be comments on the existing one.

Answer (score -2):

Add a blank item.

Comment: Hacky band-aid solutions are what's wrong with XAML