# how to avoid first item selection by default in wpf Listbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I want to avoid first item selection that happens by default in `Listbox` when application loads. I tried with

```
SelectedIndex= -1
```

but it did not work. I do not want any item to be selected when `ListBox` loads until user selects any item from `Listbox`. 
I have `IsSynchronization` set to true but making it `false` also do not solve my problem. Though i have to keep `IsSychronization` set to `true` always. But thats ok. i did google but could not find any relevant answer.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: I tried like this and it worked for me...

 `<ListBox Canvas.Left="327" Canvas.Top="145" Height="100" Name="lstBx1" Width="120" SelectedIndex="-1" />`

and when I change the index to 0 OR 1 then it shows selected..

Comment: No item is selected by default. What is `IsSychronization`?

Comment: Sorry that was IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property in Listbox.

Comment: i did SelectedIndex=-1 but it does not work. Are you sure it works for you

Answer (score 21):

I had this happen to me. When I bound `ListBox.ItemsSource` directly to a collection in my view model, the re was nothing selected by default.

When I switched to using a `CollectionViewSource` as the `ListBox.ItemsSource`, suddenly the first item was getting selected by default.

It turns out this was due to `ListBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`. Setting that to

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
```

on the `ListBox` restored the desired behavior of having nothing selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Bind IsEnabled to a boolean which will flag when the user can then select. The listbox will still be visible but non selectable. Here is style code for a label I use where it has to be enabled during login, but not once the operation stops.

```
  <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="70" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LoginInProcess}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LoginInProcess}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```